# Apply method using hash.

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I have a ruby object, say... myobject and a hash, myhash with value { op1: 'something', op2: 'something2' }.

Is there a method in ruby that let me do for example,

```
myobject.the_method(myhash)
```

So that it will work as if I did,

```
myobject.op1 'something'
myobject.op2 'something2'
```

This can be done with myhash.each and myobject.send , but is there a single method that does this? Active Support solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a method in Active Support that will do this. I recommend `each` and `send`:

```
hash.each do |method, arg|
  obj.public_send(method, arg)
end
```

Comment: There is also `public_send` which will only call public methods.

Comment: Thanks @blom! I always forget about `public_send`.